# How to delete records in django of certain type?

Tags: python, django

I am basically building a quiz game. I have three types of records stored in database- `Question`, `Answer`, `Hint`.

Now I want to add a deletion feature to the answer such that when the user deletes the answer, everything above it right upto the question will be deleted.

So a user may ask a question, get few hints and finally get the answer.Then the user chooses to delete the answer and everthing above it upto the last question gets deleted.

I know how to delete the last `n` records

```
last_n = Message.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:10].delete()
```

But this would mean in the last `n` records, there could be more than one question asked and so both questions could be deleted.

My condition needs that keep deleting right from where it is triggered to the latest message of type `Question`.

For now I can only get the message of particular type **not upto a particular type**

```
Message.objects.filter(type="Question").order_by('-id')[:10]
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Simples but not elegant is to have to iterate through the queryset and delete until you reach stopping condition where the message is of type="Question".

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you wrote your models.py file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the id of the answer is 99 (this is where the delete event is triggered) and the id of the question is 80. Also, each message entry needs to be associated to a specific user (not mentioned in your question, so I am assuming that it is like that).

```
answer = Message.objects.get(id=99)
user = answer.user
qs = Message.objects.annotate(
        last_question_id=Subquery(
            Message.objects.filter(type="question", user=user).order_by("-id").values("id")[:1]
        )
     ).filter(
         user=user, id__gt=F('last_question_id'), id__lt=answer.id
     ).delete()
```

I have made some assumptions here, and if those were wrong my answer would also be invalid.

Assumption 1: The Message model has a FK to User

Assumption 2: The user can answer only one question at a time. i.e. The Question immediately before the Answer is the Question associated with the Answer.

Assumption 3: When the User triggers a DELETE event after getting the answer, only the things between the users last question and the users last answer will be deleted.

Let me know if this was the answer you were looking for.